# Why are the bit strings representing 1.0 and 2.0 so different?

Tags: floating-point, julia, ieee-754

I recently started using Julia and I came upon the `bits` function, which returns the bit-string representation of its numeric argument. For example:

```
julia> bits(1.0)
"0011111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

However, while playing with this function, I was surprised to discover that `bits` returns very different bit strings for `1.0` and `2.0`:

```
julia> bits(1.0)
"0011111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

julia> bits(2.0)
"0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

I would have expected those two values to be similar...

**What is the meaning of those bits?** I vaguely recall something about bits encoding the exponent (from my numerical-analysis class), but I really do not remember it well and I did not manage to find a good description online...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To understand why the `ASCIIString` values of `bits(1.0)` and `bits(2.0)` are "so different", you need to know a bit (!) about [IEEE-754 (binary) floating-point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point). Each such [double-precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) number is stored as a 64-bit word, broken down into three parts:

- the sign bit (0 for nonnegative numbers, 1 for nonpositive numbers), followed by
- the [biased exponent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponent_bias) (11 bits), followed by
- the significand (52 bits).

The value of a [*normalized number*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number_(computing)) (such as `1.0` and `2.0`) can be obtained by using the following formula:

```
(-1)^sign_bit x 1.significand x 2^(biased_exponent - bias)
```

(For double-precision floating-point numbers, the bias has a value of 2^10 - 1 = 1023)

Now,

- 1.0 = +1.000... x 2^(1023 - bias)

  and 1023 corresponds to (0)1111111111 in base 2, so the corresponding bit string is

  ```
  0 01111111111 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  ```
- 2.0 = +1.000... x 2^(1024 - bias)

  and 1024 corresponds to 10000000000 in base 2, so the corresponding bit string is

  ```
  0 10000000000 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  ```
- 3.0 = +1.100... x 2^(1024 - bias)

  so the corresponding bit string is

  ```
  0 10000000000 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  ```

etc.

In summary, you can obtain the bit string of `2.0` by incrementing the biased-exponent part in the bit string of `1.0`, which is a power of 2, minus 1. Incrementing such a number causes all the bits of its binary representation to change, in the same way that incrementing the number 9999 (in decimal representation) causes all the digits to change.