# What does the exponent in a floating-point number represent?

Tags: floating-point, julia

I still don't completely understand the meaning of the representation of a factional number in Julia, specifically `0.1`:

```
bits(0.1)=0011111110111001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010
```

I know the first bit correspond to the sign of the number (`0` if positive and `1` if negative) but I don't understand what the second part `01111111011` (the next 11 bits) mean. I know I can google it but, after having visited many websites, now I'm even more confused...

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#Exponent_encoding. In particular `01111111011` is 1019, so the exponent is 1019 - 1023 = -4.  Which should make sense, as 2^(-4) <= 0.1 < 2^(-3).

Comment: A surprisingly similar question was asked a couple of days ago; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32157869/why-are-the-bit-strings-representing-1-0-and-2-0-so-different/32159972#32159972

Comment: “decimal” means “written in base 10”. You appear to want “fractional”.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`01111111011`, when encoding the exponent of a double-precision IEEE 754 floating-point number, means -4. This is the exponent that all numbers between 0.06125 (included) and 0.125 (excluded) have, since it means the number is of the form m * 2^e with 1 ≤ m < 2 and e = -4.

This sequence of bits represents this exponent because exponent are stored as unsigned numbers (`01111111011` as an unsigned number is 1019) with a bias of 1023. The actual exponent should be computed as 1019 - 1023, that is, -4.